# Create a multidimensional vector from a text file

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have the following problem:

I have a file that looks like:

```
1 2 4 5 7 8
3 1 3 7 8 9 10 11
2 4 1 3 5
4 5 6 7
```

I want to create different vectors in which:

```
vector[0][0]=1 , vector[0][1]=2, ... , vector[1][0]=3, vector[1][1]=1 etc etc
```

I am still at the beginning and I tried with:

```
my $file = 'file.dat';
open (INFO, $file);
my @vector = <INFO>;
close (INFO);
```

but it only creates an array that read what is contained in the file and do not confer to an exact position (as the result that I am expecting) the elements of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the file, split the lines and put them inside an anonymous array that you push onto your main array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# Use the lines below for your real data
#my $file = 'file.dat';
#open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";
my @vector;
while (<DATA>) {   # replace <DATA> with <$fh>
    push @vector, [ split ];
}
print Dumper \@vector;

__DATA__
1 2 4 5 7 8
3 1 3 7 8 9 10 11
2 4 1 3 5
4 5 6 7
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1',
            '2',
            '4',
            '5',
            '7',
            '8'
          ],
          [
            '3',
            '1',
            '3',
            '7',
            '8',
            '9',
            '10',
            '11'
          ],
          [
            '2',
            '4',
            '1',
            '3',
            '5'
          ],
          [
            '4',
            '5',
            '6',
            '7'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: Sorry but how can I open the data file? If the file is named `file.dat` how can I say in the script to go and find the datas in this file?

Comment: You have already opened the file in your code. Were you not aware of this? Because it looked like you were. Though you should use three-argument open and a lexical file handle. And also check the return value of your open statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that very simply using `map` and a regular expression to pick out the numeric substrings `my @vector = map [ /\d+/g ], <FILEHANDLE>`

This program reads from the `DATA` file handle to facilitate the demonstration. You would normally open a file yourself using `open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die $!` and read from that file handle.

`Data::Dump` is there only to display the data structure and is otherwise unnecessary.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @vector = map [ /\d+/g ], <DATA>;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@vector;

say "\$vector[0][0] = $vector[0][0]";
say "\$vector[0][1] = $vector[0][1]";
say "\$vector[1][0] = $vector[1][0]";
say "\$vector[1][1] = $vector[1][1]";


__DATA__
1 2 4 5 7 8
3 1 3 7 8 9 10 11
2 4 1 3 5
4 5 6 7
```

**output**

```
[
  [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8],
  [3, 1, 3, 7 .. 11],
  [2, 4, 1, 3, 5],
  [4 .. 7],
]
$vector[0][0] = 1
$vector[0][1] = 2
$vector[1][0] = 3
$vector[1][1] = 1
```